How to mix bold and text small caps using lualatex?
I expected John Smith to be formatted like Jane Doe but it is not. Please help diagnose this mishap. The problem only manifests itself with luatex which I need for emojis (1).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\FirstLast}{mm}{\__erw_firstlast:nn{#1}{#2}}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\LastName}{m}{\__erw_lastname:n{#1} }
\cs_new:Nn\__erw_firstlast:nn{#1~\__erw_lastname:n{#2}}
\cs_new:Nn\__erw_lastname:n{\textsc{\text_titlecase:n{#1}}}
\cs_new:Nn\__erw_bold:n{\textbf{#1}}
\cs_new:Nn\__erw_subject:n{\noindent\exp_args:Nx\__erw_bold:n{#1}}
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\Subject}{m}{\__erw_subject:n{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{Regarding \FirstLast{John}{Smith}'s letter}

\noindent Dear \FirstLast{Jane}{Doe},

\noindent \rule{4em}{0.4pt}

\Subject{Regarding \FirstLast{John}{Smith}'s letter}

\end{document}

(1) Also Unicode 2014, "—", does not display correctly, but -- provides a workaround.



look into the log-file. It tells you that the font doesn't exist. Use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

@UlrikeFischer it now works with the addition of the suggested package. However my working file (not debug) already had it, so I'm going to double check.

When using LuaLaTeX, you shouldn't run \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

naturally U+2014 would not work in luatex as you have specified T1 (8 bit legacy tex encoding) so no unicode slots above 256 will work.


Please help diagnose this mishap.

Under LuaLaTeX, the default font family is Latin Modern Roman, which doesn't feature the bold-smallcaps weight/shape font combination. In contrast, under pdfLaTeX the default font family is Computer Modern Roman, which -- in conjunction with running \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} -- does feature the desired weight/shape font combination.
What to do under LuaLaTeX? I can only suggest using a font that does feature the desired bold-smallcaps combination. One such font, which is quite similar to the original Computer Modern Roman, is "CMU Serif". Here, "CMU" is short for "Computer Modern Unicode" and not, say, "Carnegie Mellon University". :-)

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  % if no font package is specified, use "Computer Modern" font
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{CMU Serif} % or some other suitable font
\fi

\begin{document}
Hello World \quad \textsc{Hello World} \quad \textbf{\textsc{Hello World}}
\end{document}


The requirement (sc+bf) is met with that font in luatex. However could you recommend one that is also similar to the original style (I presume that is computer modern).

@erwann - I suggest you try CMU Serif (where CMU is short for Computer Modern Serif). I should have thought of this possibility myself before posting the answer. In fact, I'll go ahead and update my answer to incorporate this idea.
